# Sumar elementos de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estoy haciendo un consulta donde me obtenga el saldo del total de la tabla `VentaComision` y el total `ComisionCobrada`:

```
SELECT * FROM VentaComision;
```

| Id | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 284 | 104.55 |
| 285 | 104.55 |

```
SELECT * FROM ComisionCobrada;
```

| Id | IdVentaComision | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 72 | 284 | 50.00 |
| 73 | 284 | 54.55 |
| 74 | 285 | 4.47 |

Al sacar la diferencia el `SUM(vc.Total)` me está sumando 2 veces el total del Id 284. Tendría que sumarse solo una vez el `Total`.

```
SELECT (SUM(vc.Total) - SUM(cc.Total)) as saldo FROM VentaComision vc
LEFT JOIN ComisionCobrada cc ON cc.IdVentaComision = vc.Id
```

| saldo |
| --- |
| 204.63 |

Comment: En una consulta como la que estás haciendo se genera una fila de la primera tabla por cada coincidencia en la segunda. Lo que necesitas es una subconsulta que calcule la suma. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas restar la suma de los elementos de una tabla a la suma de los elementos de la otra tabla, entonces esta es la consulta que necesitas:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Total) - (
      SELECT SUM(Total) FROM ComisionCobrada
    ) as saldo 
FROM VentaComision
```

El funcionamiento es sencillo: a la suma de los totales de la tabla `VentaComision` le resta el resultado de la subconsulta, que es la suma de los totales de la tabla `ComisionCobrada`.

Puedes ver su funcionamiento en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifwbe1RHPX1KZ9LTdtpdih/0

Si lo que necesitas es un listado de cada una de las transacciones, entonces es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Total,
    Total - (
      SELECT SUM(Total) FROM ComisionCobrada cc
      WHERE vc.Id = cc.IdVentaComision
    ) as saldo
FROM VentaComision vc;
```

Puedes ver esta última en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifwbe1RHPX1KZ9LTdtpdih/1